# Склонение слова "мир"

Tags: лингвистика

Как сложилось, что, когда мы говорим о мире как о Вселенной или как об антиподе войны, то говорим "в мире", но, если речь об антиподе монашества, мы говорим "в миру"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Хороший вопрос.

Дело в том, что некоторые слова имеют две формы предложного падежа.
Первая используется когда говорят о предмете и в большинстве других случаев, вторая используется только с предлогами В и НА и только когда речь идёт о месте, она обычно отвечает на вопрос "где?", иногда в переносном смысле.
Для мужского рода эти формы отличаются окончанием -а и -у: О лесе, О льде, О дыме, О к**о**не (ставке), но В лесу, НА льду, В дыму, НА кону.

Вторая форма - рефлекс древнего **местного** падежа, именно она используется в форме "в миру" (вселенная), в том числе и в значении - "светская жизнь". Но при этом "о мире". Омоним же "мир" (спокойствие, не война) - такой формы не имеет, поэтому, например, "жили в мире".

Единственное слово, допускающее эту форму "местного падежа" с другим предлогом - полк: "о полку", наряду с "о полке", возможно связано с созвучностью последней формы со словом "полка". А может и с известностью "Слова о полку Игореве".

Аналогичную форму имеют и некоторые слова женского рода на -ь, но там разница ограничивается смещением ударения на флексию: о шЕрсти, но в шерстИ.

Answer (score 0):

Уважаемый Sefes!
Во-первых, в вашем вопросе не нужна запятая перед "когда", ибо это стык союзов и после придаточной следует "то". 
Во-вторых, непонятно, какое такое значение "антипод монашества". Возможно, вы имеете в виду *мир как светская жизнь, не связанная со служением церкви, Богу ([слово "мир" в 9 значении](http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?word=%EC%E8%F0&all=x)*). Тогда я думаю, что определенные значения слов начали своеобразно склоняться по падежам, для того чтобы в устной речи, как, впрочем, и в письменной, можно было понять в каком значении говорится слово *"мир"*, ибо много значений у него. Думаю, такой же логикой руководствуются, когда пишут *"Мир"* с большой буквы.

Comment: Валентин! Вы так любите делать замечания, указывать на ошибки, а сами? Что это: значения слов начали склоняться (склоняются слова. а не значения), склоняться по падежам (склоняться - это и есть изменяться по падежам).

Comment: Валентин, спасибо за Ваши ответы, но будьте деликатнее. Вам не кажется, что Вы обижаете спрашивающих? То, что очевидно для вас, не всегда известно другим. Форум создан для того, чтобы прояснять трудные для человека вопросы, а не объяснять ему, что он дебил.
С уважением,
администратор

Comment: По-моему про антипод монашества сказано кратко и понятно. Вы же поняли? Ну и не "цепляйтесь" к человеку.

Comment: Ларf, спасибо, что заметили. Это я, видимо по невнимательности ошибся.
Fuchoin Kazuk, я как-то привык к столь немного грубому выражению своих мыслей. Извините. Постараюсь быть повежливее и деликатнее.
Docent, когда я прочёл первый раз сообщение, то не понял и скопировал совершенно другое значение слова "мир" из словаря, но потом понял, что имел ввиду спрашивающий, поменял понятие на другое, а прелюдию оставил ту же.

Comment: @Валентин, у Вас есть возможность править свои ответы, если Вы обнаружили ошибку. Кроме того, если Вы поставите перед ником @, то он станет ссылкой на участника. У некоторых участников это учитывается в настройках, т.е. мы получаем по почте те комментарии, которые содержат такую ссылку. Только для этого надо писать ник точно (я для этого просто копирую ники).

Comment: @DocentI , спасибо за интересную информацию.