# Почему такое окончание?

Tags: грамотная-речь

Тут уже задавали вопросы о вариации окончаний "-е" и "-у", но сейчас меня интересует слово "Крым". Почему, например, "в доме", но — "в Крыму"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

О Крыме, но в Крыму; о доме, но на дому (заниматься, например); о лесе, но в лесу. Варианты с окончанием у - "остатки" местного падежа, который был раньше.

Answer (score 0):

В таблице склонений по падежам у ["дома"](http://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%BC) и у ["Крыма"](http://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D1%80%D1%8B%D0%BC) одинаковые окончания. Возможно, в вашем примере разные падежи употреблены.

Answer (score 0):

Да, это "местный падеж", он же локатив, он же "второй предложный".

Подробнее [здесь](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/5381/%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0-%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%80), правда применительно к другому слову.